# Why does the UI hang when I show AletView on background thread?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uialertview

I have shown an `UIAlertView` from a thread, but the UI hangs and then shows `UIAlertView` after 2-3 seconds.

I can use `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue...` or `performSelectorOnMainThread` to fix this.

I want to know why the UI hangs when we present any `UIAlertView` on background thread.

Comment: did you see my answer? does it help?

Comment: I didn't downvote, I just put an answer...

Comment: if my answer explains the issue, could you tick the green arrow please? @ManojAher

Comment: I don't mean you should upvote it, you can just click on the checkmark to mark the question as solved. :)

Comment: not why they'd downvote your question. I think it's rather clear and does adhere to the SO standards... was the issue solved btw?

Comment: was the issue solved? could you please click the green checkmark of my answer if that's the case or otherweise specify what is still unclear :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On iOS, **all UI operations have to performed on the main thread**, you can't have UI operations (such as showing an `UIAlertView`) on a background thread. That's also the explanation why `performSelectorOnMainThread:` fixes the issue.

Here is a nice [blog post](http://iosdevelopmentjournal.com/blog/2013/01/16/forcing-things-to-run-on-the-main-thread/) on the topic and a [link to the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaPerformance/Articles/UnblockUI.html).